# How to fix: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined" error in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js bot and I've put a leaderboard command in it.

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
  // Get a filtered list (for this guild only), and convert to an array while we're at it.
  const filtered = client.points.filter( p => p.guild === message.guild.id ).array();

  // Sort it to get the top results... well... at the top. Y'know.
  const sorted = filtered.sort((a, b) => b.points - a.points);

  // Slice it, dice it, get the top 10 of it!
  const top10 = sorted.splice(0, 10);

  // Now shake it and show it! (as a nice embed, too!)
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Leaderboard")
    .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL)
    .setDescription("Our top 10 points leaders!")
    .setColor(0xff0000);
  for(const data of top10) {
    embed.addField(client.users.get(data.user).tag, `${data.points} points (level ${data.level})`);
  }
  return message.channel.send({embed});
}
```

But when I run the command I get this in the command line/logs:

```
    embed.addField(client.users.get(data.user).tag, `${data.points} points (level ${data.level})`);

                                              ^


TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined

at Object.exports.run (/app/commands/leaderboard.js:19:47)

at module.exports (/app/events/message.js:19:7)

    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)

    at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)

    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/461f582b-2c68-44a2-912c-88cd1fefb0fa/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)

    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/461f582b-2c68-44a2-912c-88cd1fefb0fa/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)

    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/461f582b-2c68-44a2-912c-88cd1fefb0fa/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)

    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/461f582b-2c68-44a2-912c-88cd1fefb0fa/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)

    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/461f582b-2c68-44a2-912c-88cd1fefb0fa/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ws/4.1.0/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)

    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

I've transferred the bot from my pc to glitch.com which seemed to fix it for a while, but now the problem is back.

Comment: How does data.user look? You know, that you have to use the ID of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means `client.users.get(data.user)` is returning undefined, hence there cannot be a property `tag` on it. Presumably this means the user specified in data does not exist.

You should add some defensive code before directly trying to access the property to ensure that the `get()` call returns something rather than undefined.

For example

```
const user = client.users.get(data.user);
if (user && user.tag) {
  // code here
} else {
  // user does not exist..
}
```

Comment: Although it's good practice to make sure something is returned, using [`client#users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) to find a user is not. It only contains previously cached users. The proper way to find a Discord user is [`client#fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser).

Answer (score 1):

`client.users.get(data.user)` is undefined in your code. Straight from the Discord.js docs, [`Client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) is...

> All of the User objects **that have been cached** at any point, mapped by their IDs

Instead of relying solely on the client's cache, you can retrieve the user from the Discord API using the [`Client.fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser) method. Keep in mind, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```js
// async context required to use 'await'
await client.fetchUser(data.user);
```